# LDAP SSO between portal built in Laravel and SAS

Tags: laravel, sas, ldap, single-sign-on

We have built a portal in PHP(Laravel) + Angular for a client. User Authentication is done through LDAP.

Client also has a SAS solution for Analytics and it also has LDAP Authentication (SAS Viya).

We need to redirect the user from our portal to SAS portal and the user should get logged in automatically as both portals are authenticating the users through same LDAP.

We tried a few things, but it didn't help.

I am looking for some guidance on how to implement this and if there is any programming/configuration required on our side or on SAS side.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be specific without fully understanding your use case, but you could look to handle authentication to Viya using the SASjs Adapter (disclaimer - my team built it)

https://github.com/sasjs/adapter

Just set the `LoginMechanism` to `REDIRECTED` in the config object to support SSO or alternative login flows.  If you need help, my team can be contact on https://sasapps.io/contact-us, else just raise an issue on the github.

We have an implementation on Angular that may help:  https://github.com/sasjs/angular-seed-app

Answer (score 0):

We have integrated a VIYA Visual Analytics report into a corporate web application, using the SDK (so not realy a redirect) with single sign on.

(I don't know all the details about how we did it. my roll was in the personalization of the report, where we went further than ordinary row level security.)